# How do I replace one element in an array with potentially multiple elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to replace an item in an array:

```
arr = ["55", "4.ARTHUR", "masddf"]
```

with potentially multiple items based on whether it matches a regular expression. I would like to have the result:

```
["55", "4.", "ARTHUR", "masddf"]
```

I tried:

```
arr.map { |o| o =~ /\d+\./ ? o.split(/^(\d+\.)/).reject { |c| c.empty? } : o }
# => ["55", ["4.", "ARTHUR"], "masddf"]

arr.map { |o| o =~ /\d+\./ ? o.split(/^(\d+\.)/).reject { |c| c.empty? }.flatten : o }
# => ["55", ["4.", "ARTHUR"], "masddf"]
```

I can't seem to get the elements outside of the array they got split into. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) instead:

```
arr = ["55", "4.ARTHUR", "masddf"]
arr.flat_map { |o| o =~ /\d+\./ ? o.split(/^(\d+\.)/).reject { |c| c.empty? } : o }
# => ["55", "4.", "ARTHUR", "masddf"]
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/F90V

By the way, a simpler way to solve this problem is to use [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
arr.flat_map {|o| o.scan(/^\d+\.|.+/) }
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/F90V/1